# why not java.lang.Object class is abstact class?

Tags: java

I think a proprem in this night,
As we all know,all classes's super class is `java.lang.Object`,
but why not it is abstract class??

Comment: Why do you think it should be? Putting your thoughts in the question would really improve it.

Comment: which is itself closed as a duplicate

Comment: There was a thinking that abstract classes should have abstract methods.  Object could have been abstract, but it is indirectly useful that it is not as sometimes you want a generic Object.

Answer (score 2):

You could argue that it was simply an arbitrary design decision but the main benefit is that by not marking the class abstract you can create instances of type `Object`.

Since all of the methods of the `Object` class are fully implemented there was no inherent benefit in marking it abstract.

Comment: +1 for arbitrary designs decision.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` does not have any abstract methods so making the class abstract would prevent it from being instantiated (although you would be able through: `new Object() {};`) which is an unnecessary restriction.

And it happens that being able to instantiate an Object is sometimes handy, for example to create a lock:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```